# Scatter plot remains grey

Tags: reactjs, plot, victory-charts

I am using React [Victory](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/) to plot different datasets and functions in a project. However I am unable to color scatter plot points.

I have tried with the following piece of code:

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import { VictoryChart, VictoryScatter, VictoryTheme } from 'victory';

    import './input_component.css'

    class InputComponent extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {  }
        }

    render() { 
        return ( 
        <div className = "input_layer">
            <VictoryChart
            theme={VictoryTheme.material}
            domain={{ x: [-1, 1], y: [-1, 1] }}>
                <VictoryScatter
                size={5}
                data={[{x:-0.7, y:1, fill: "blue"}, {x:0.5, y:-0.2, fill: "red"}]}
                />
            </VictoryChart>
        </div> 

        );
    }
  }

  export default InputComponent;
```

From this I get a scatter plot chart, however all data points are grey instead of the color I specify as the "fill" argument.

Looking at the documentation for the data prop [here](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/common-props/#data), it would seem like I should be able to specify a color through the "fill" argument.

If anyone has suggestions to what I am doing wrong, I would be glad to hear them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's late but it will help someone.
Using style prop in victoryScatter will solve your problem.

```
<VictoryScatter
    size={5}
    data={[{x:-0.7, y:1, fill: "blue"}, {x:0.5, y:-0.2, fill: "red"}]}
    style={{
    data: {
      fill: ({ datum }) => datum.fill,
    }
  }}
/>
```

You can add any style property you want in the style props.